# (node.js) How do I call upon this middleware function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

https://repl.it/join/vwrhgruw-davidnguyen32

I'm completely new to Node.js and am trying to call upon a function, but keep receiving an error that I got an Object and not a middleware function.  Sorry I'm new to Stackoverflow and am not familar with all the requirements to post.

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require("fs");
const handlebars = require('handlebars');
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', (request, response) => {
    let result = "";
    if  (request.query.inches) {
        result = processLength(inches);
    }
    else {
        result = "Unexpected submit value: " + submit;
    }
    response.send(result);
});

function processLength() {
    let result = "";
    if (request.query.inches) {
        let inches = request.query.inches;
        let f = inches / 12;
        let feet = f.toFixed(2);
        let y = inches / 36;
        let yards = y.toFixed(2);
        result = inches + " inches is " +
            feet + " feet or " + yards + " yards";
    }
    result = template(data);
    return result
}
```

I wanted to submit my template page but wasn't able to.

Comment: Welcome !! Here's a link to familiarize you with how to ask questions on StackOverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

`processLength()` is not middleware.  It's just a function you're trying to call from a request handler.  It's a stand-alone function so it doesn't know anything about any `request` or `response`variables because you didn't pass either of those arguments to it.  If you want it to know about the `request` object inside that function, then you can pass that object to the function as an argument like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const fs = require("fs");
const handlebars = require('handlebars');
const router = express.Router()

router.post('/', (request, response) => {
    let result = "";
    if  (request.query.inches) {
        result = processLength(request);
    }
    else {
        result = "Unexpected submit value: " + submit;
    }
    response.send(result);
});

function processLength(req) {
    let result = "";
    if (req.query.inches) {
        let inches = req.query.inches;
        let f = inches / 12;
        let feet = f.toFixed(2);
        let y = inches / 36;
        let yards = y.toFixed(2);
        result = inches + " inches is " +
            feet + " feet or " + yards + " yards";
    }
    // problem here - it's not clear what `data` is?
    result = template(data);
    return result
}
```

This solves the problem of making the request object available inside of the `processLength` function.  However, you're calling `template(data)` inside that function and there does not appear to be any `data` variable defined so you will also have to fix that.

This line of code:

```
 result = "Unexpected submit value: " + submit;
```

also has a problem because `submit` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for you help, trying too many examples made it messier as I went on.

Comment: @Bormimor - Since it appears you may be new here, if this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some stackoverflow reputation points for following the proper procedure.